# "Dynamic" frame in Java

Tags: java, swing

In my program, I have one frame with tabs in it. Each tab will have its own panels and offer different features. However, within the tab, I've been trying to figure out a way to make it dynamic without constantly removing components from the main panel (the main panel being the one used inside the tab) and re-adding other components. I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Here's an example of what I mean inside of one of the tabs:

```
if("Back".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        Events_Panel.remove(Event_Detail_Pane);
        Events_Panel.remove(Event_Detail_Button);
        Events_Screen();
        Pane_Refresh(Events_Panel);
}
```

Where Pane_Refresh(JPanel pane) and Events_Screen() are defined as

```
public void Events_Screen() {
    Events_Panel.add(listpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Events_Panel.add(listpane_buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void Pane_Refresh(JPanel pane) {
    pane.revalidate();
    pane.repaint();
}
```

The User presses the back button and the frame changes to the components that came beforehand (removing/adding and then revalidating and repainting everything). This seems like a very inefficient way to do this. Does anyone have any better ideas? I was thinking that maybe using `.setVisibile()` would work, but I have not had very much experience using it.

Also, this question may have been answered at some point, however I could not find it and was not sure what exactly to look up for a question that may have pertained to this.

Comment: Have you looked at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)? [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Hmmm, it appears this solves the problem quite nicely. I had heard about CardLayout, but from how it sounded, I thought it was just another layout manager to get a certain look inside the frame.

Comment: Another thing that frequently happens in this program is that a list gets updated, meaning the JList and the scrollpane have to be updated. A textarea is also updated depending on what list item is selected. So, in that case, would I have to still remove, add, revalidate, and repaint in order to "refresh" those panels?

Comment: *" JList and the scrollpane have to be updated. A textarea is also updated depending on what list item is selected"* - Why should any of this require you to remove any components?  Simply update the `JList` model as required and change the text of the text area as required

Comment: Well, I didn't know about the CardLayout, so that fixes the majority of my problems. Likewise, so does `setModel` and `setText`. However, the JList is supposed to appear in the JScrollPane. The problem is that when the list is updated JScrollPane only updates when I remove the original scrollpane, create a new one from the same JList, and then add it and revalidate/repaint. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to solve this with `setViewportView`